# ASP VB Script / Dreamweaver Clickable Results Link

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am building a document catalogue in Dreamweaver CS6 using asp VB Script and Access as my DB. I have a "documents" table with attributes of

```
   -refid (PK) .........(this is an auto#)
   -docname ...........(Description of the doc)
   -location ..............(e.g. "images\Power Point\Smart-Wireless-Overview-16x9.pptx")
   -typeid (FK).......(e.g. Manual, Presentation, Drawing etc)
   -modelcode.........(e.g. 3051S, 3144 etc)
```

I am building a search field where the user can enter a search criteria and the system should display the document.
I was able to design the search and get accurate results however I am unable to get a clickable link for the user to view or download the document.  All that is appearing on the browser is the actual link stored in the DB.

Is there any way for me to get a link or icon for the user to click to view the document?

------SEARCH CODE------

```
<h2>Select A Search Criteria</h2>
<div id="search_options">
  <form name="form1" method="post" action="Result.asp">
    <label for="input"></label>
    <input type="text" name="input" id="input">
    <input type="submit" name="search_btn" id="search_btn" value="Submit">
  </form>
</div>


------RESULTS CODE------
 <h2>Content Found</h2>
    <div id="results">Content for  id "results" Goes Here
      <% If Not Search.EOF Or Not Search.BOF Then %>
  <table border="1">
    <tr>
      <td>refid</td>
      <td>docname</td>
      <td>location</td>
      <td>typeid</td>
      <td>modelcode</td>
      <td>Details</td>
    </tr>
    <% While ((Repeat1__numRows <> 0) AND (NOT Search.EOF)) %>
      <tr>
        <td><%=(Search.Fields.Item("refid").Value)%></td>
        <td><%=(Search.Fields.Item("docname").Value)%></td>
        <td><%=(Search.Fields.Item("location").Value)%></td>
        <td><%=(Search.Fields.Item("typeid").Value)%></td>
        <td><%=(Search.Fields.Item("modelcode").Value)%></td>
        <td> <a href="ResultsDetails.asp?<%= Server.HTMLEncode(MM_keepNone) & MM_joinChar(MM_keepNone) & "refid=" & search.Fields.Item("refid").Value%>">View</a></td> 
      </tr>
      <% 
  Repeat1__index=Repeat1__index+1
  Repeat1__numRows=Repeat1__numRows-1
  Search.MoveNext()
Wend
%>
  </table>
  <% End If ' end Not Search.EOF Or NOT Search.BOF %>
    </div>
    </section>



-----DETAILS CODE-----

 <p>Content for  id "results" Goes Here</p>
      <p><img src="images/Data_Sheets/00813-0100-4001.pdf" width="82" height="73" longdesc="<%=(Details.Fields.Item("location").Value)%>"></p>
      <p><%=(Details.Fields.Item("location").Value)%></p>
    </div>
    </section>
```